# How to call Second API call on Success response of First API Using Flutter Bloc

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, bloc

I am working on flutter app which has profile screen where user can view profile data and on a Edit tap can update the same data.

Now on a save button user gets updated profile data like email,username etc successfully and then on a success response i also wants to call api where user can send OTP on a updated email and on a success response of that user will be redirected to Verify OTP Screen.

My _getSaveButton will have a code snippet like a below:

```
Widget _getSaveButton() {
    var email = _emailController.text;

    return BlocListener<EditProfileBloc, EditProfileState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state is EditProfileInitial) {
          print("Edit Profile Initial");
        } else if (state is EditProfileCompletedState) {
            // First API CALL
           print("Edit Profile Completed");
          Utilities(context).showTextSnackBar(state.response.message);
          sendEmailOtpBloc.add(SendEmailOtpSuccessEvent(email));
         // SECOND API 
          getSendOTPAPI();

          // Utilities(context).pushScreenNamed(ScreenNames.verifyEmailOtpName);
        } else if (state is EditProfileFailedState) {
          Utilities(context).showTextSnackBar(state.response.message);
        }
      },
      child: IconButton(
        onPressed: () {
          onSaveButtonTap();
        },
        icon: Text(
          RazullString.save,
          style: RazullTextStyles.gorditaMedium.copyWith(
            fontSize: 14.sp,
            color: RazullColors.buttonPrimaryColor,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

//

```
getSendOTPAPI() {
    print("Send Email Data");
    BlocListener<SendEmailOtpBloc, SendEmailOtpState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        print(state);
        if (state is SendEmailOtpInitial) {
          print("Send EMAIL OTP INITIAL");
        } else if (state is SendEmailOtpCompletedState) {
          print("SEND OTP : ${state.response.message}");
          Utilities(context).showTextSnackBar(state.response.message);
          Future.delayed(
            const Duration(
              seconds: Constants.snackBarDelay,
            ),
          ).then((value) {
            Utilities(context).pushScreenNamed(
              ScreenNames.verifyEmailOtpName,
            );
          });
        } else if (state is SendEmailOtpFailedState) {
          Utilities(context).showTextSnackBar(state.response.message);
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

I am able to get second API call but unable to get redirect to another screen becuase compiler is not getting into SendEmailOtpCompletedState.

This is how my SendEmailOtpBloc will look a like

```
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
import 'package:razull_mobile/bloc/profile/editProfile/sendEmailOTP/SendEmailOTPResponseSuccessful.dart';
import 'package:razull_mobile/model/auth/generic_response.dart';
import 'package:razull_mobile/repository/profile/edit_profile_repository.dart';
import 'package:razull_mobile/utils/utilities.dart';

part 'send_email_otp_event.dart';
part 'send_email_otp_state.dart';

class SendEmailOtpBloc extends Bloc<SendEmailOtpEvent, SendEmailOtpState> {
  final EditProfileRepository editProfileRepository = EditProfileRepository();
  SendEmailOtpBloc() : super(SendEmailOtpInitial()) {
    on<SendEmailOtpEvent>((event, emit) {
      emit(SendEmailOtpInitial());
    });

    on<SendEmailOtpSuccessEvent>((event, emit) async {
      emit(SendEmailOtpInitial());

      var email = event.emailID;

      RazullAPIResponse response =
          await editProfileRepository.sentEmailOtp(email);

      if (response is SendEmailOTPResponseSuccessful) {
        emit(SendEmailOtpCompletedState(response));
      } else if (response is SendEmailOTPResponseFailed) {
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print("Unblock Failed Message: ${response.message}");
          print("Unblock Failed Status Code: ${response.statusCode}");
        }
        emit(SendEmailOtpFailedState(response));
      }
    });
  }
}
```